# Can I Only Export the visible items in a DevExpress Grid

Tags: asp.net, pdf, devexpress, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

We have data using DevExpress Grid on a web application, and the users are asking to only export the visible data from the page. At the moment, if we do an export, it exports everything from the grid, whether it is shown on the current page, or on a future page (200 items, 20 pages, showing only page 4, we export everything).

We are using the WritePdfToResponse (if its a PDF file as an example) and tried using the PdfExportOptions PageRange, but it seems to only work for Pages of the PDF file, not the data... For example, if there are 200 items to display, on the site it shows as 20 pages, but in PDF, it shows up as 4 or 5 pages. If we want only page 4, we get page 4 of the PDF, not of the site... Can this be done? Ideally, for PDF, CVS, RTF and XSL...

Answer (score 0):

The grid exporter exports the entire data from the **ASPxGridView** control. However, if you temporarily bind the grid to a visible page only, and then export it, you will get the same result.

For example, you can get the grid's page index to determine what user sees on the screen and that fetch these records from the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you can select required range of rows and set the [ExportedRowType](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewExportASPxGridViewExporter_ExportedRowTypetopic) property of the [ASPxGridViewExporter](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxGridViewExportASPxGridViewExportertopic) to Selected.

Please also review the following help topics:
 - [Export Overview](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3791)
 - [Selection](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3737)

Comment: Due to the way the application is setup, with details views, selecting is only one at a time... If we change it to work with multiple selectable, we break the rest of the page functionality...

Comment: Also, your links point to devexpress.dev... is this an internal site?

Comment: @TiernanO: Sorry for my mistake with links... Now I've updated them.
You can enable multiselection only while exporting and then disable it.